# Priorities the value in the ngx-charts-line-chart on single #tooltipTemplate

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular7, angular-chart, ngx-charts

I am trying to prioritize the value in the ngx-charts-line-chart. The scenario with the current chart is that it show's the last element value on single point indication.

From the below data all the countries have the same value for the year 2010. Now when I hover on the single indication it always shows the value of the last element, however, I want to display the first or second element of the array.

Here is the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-bar-chart-yvy5bx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Is there any way to show the Germany when I hover for the year 2010?

```
export var multi = [
  {
    "name": "Germany",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7300000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 3400000
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "USA",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7300000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 9800000
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "France",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7300000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 7300000
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

[image: Image of the results]

Comment: what do you mean by "Is there any way to show the Germany when I hover for the year 2010?"... you mean when you hover over year 2010 (in the x-axis)? or when you hover over the germany point for 2010?

Comment: As shown in the figure. It currently shows the last element of data, but I need to show the first element or second element of the data. In my case, Germany is the first item.